# Converting n to m relationship with specialization to relational model

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship, relational-model

I'm finding the best way to convert an eer diagram to the corresponding relational diagram. I have a generalization entity with some specializations which have separate relationships with other entities. The generalization entity has in turn a n-to-m relationsip with an entity. The following drawing clarifies the situation:
[Eer diagram with specialization and n-to-m relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s74Op.png).

As the two specialized entities have separate relationships, I should convert them to two separate tables. Meanwhile, I should create a table modeling the n-to-m relationship which relates the entity 'User' to the entity 'Newsletter' (or better, its specializations). How to cope with this problem? I've not found any useful information.

The only possible solution I thought to was to create two separate tables modeling the n-to-m relationship, one linked to 'User' and 'Programming newsletter' tables, one linked to 'User' and 'Travel newsletter' tables. But I'm looking for opinions for that.

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem.  I would implement your diagram using the following tables:

```
User (nickname PK, name, address)
Newsletter (name PK, supervisor, type)
Subscription (user_nickname PK/FK, newsletter_name PK/FK)
Programming_Newsletter (newsletter_name PK/FK, type FK, language)
Travel_Newsletter (newsletter_name PK/FK, type FK, means_of_transport)
```

I probably wouldn't use user nicknames / newsletter names as keys since I prefer stable compact identifiers, but that's another topic.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of ways to go about this.

The simplest one, would be to break the assumption "As the two specialized entities have separate relationships, I should convert them to two separate tables". If you keep your specialisations together in a single table, you can use **[STI (Single table inheritance)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)** for your generalisation. This approach has a drawback though, which is that your table will have many NULL values for those relationships that do not belong to the concrete specialisation.

The other approach, would be to use **[CTI (Class Table Inheritance)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html)**. This approach assumes that there will be a specific table for each specialisation of your generalisation. This would get around the NULL problems, but it can potentially introduce a performance problem due to the fact that your code will need to eagerly join from the generalisation table to the specialisation on almost every single query you make to retrieve them.

I don't quite see the issue in the n-to-m relationship between User and Newsletter. You should be able to have a regular intermediate table that creates the association between the two, since there are no further attributes that complement that relationship.

Comment: Why would you have to join with the supertype table on almost every query involving the subtypes?  Unless you need the supervisor, there's no need to join on that table.

Comment: If the super-type has common attributes for its sub-types (which is something quite normal) you need to join to that table so you can access them to form a fully fleshed object.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  Since I decompose my systems into SQL-speaking service objects rather than domain objects, getting "fully fleshed objects" from the DB is never a concern.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I apprecciated both hasumedic and reaanb approaches. I was wondering if it was possible to implement this eer diagram with a table-per-specialized class architecture without having a table for the superclass. Can you tell me something about that?

Comment: That would be @reaanb's suggestion. The only caviat would be that common fields in every newsletter would generate some redundancy. If that doesn't bother you, and your model is pretty stable (you won't be adding/removing newsletter types often), that approach should work. If it's uncertain and it might change frequently, I'd use a STI.

Comment: @hasumedic No, that's not my suggestion.  Check my answer, I included a supertype table, which is required for foreign key constraints at least.

Comment: I solved my issue (in fact I did as reaanb suggested) but actually no answer to the original question has been provided, i.e. how to convert that eer diagram to its corresponding relational model with separate tables for subclasses and without a table for the main entity.